# how to write out a tokenized string

Tags: c, string, split, strtok, scanf

I am quite new to C and any examples I have found of my problem didn't seem to work, or I completely misunderstood what that solution was.  I have a large file with data that looks like:

LYS  24L  HB2  45.212   39.585  124.457 SC0  0.145 -0.795  0.585  0.157

on each line.  I have tokenized the data already using strtok. What I need is from the second field, I wish to have the 24 stored as an integer for comparison, and the L to be stored as a char for comparison as well.

I tried using

```
sscanf(token[1], "%d%s", number, letter);
```

but I keep getting Segmentation fault error.  Also upon further experimenting with sscanf i tried simply to print out "LYS" (in attempt to further understand my problem) however my program would only print L using the following command:

```
sscanf(token[0], "%c", &stemp);
letter = stemp;
printf("%c \n", letter);
```

However if change %c ---> %s (hoping to obtain the whole string) then I obtain the Segmentation fault error once again ... Is there something I do not understand about the sscanf command?  Why can i not read in a full string??  Thank you in advance for your time and help!!

Paul

Comment: can you post the whole segment of code you use to tokenize the line?

Comment: enable core dumps '$ulimit -c unlimited'. then run gdb to examine where exactly segmentation fault occurs. i suspect its in token[1]. token[1] seems to be the faulty reference. but without seeing how token allocated and initialized, its tough to be sure. please include codes which allocated and initialized the "token" array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the issue is actually that `number` and `letter` are of type `int` and `char`, respectively. `scanf()` needs addresses of memory locations in which to store the values, not the variables themselves; i.e.,

```
int number;
char letter[2];

sscanf(token[1], "%d%s", &number, letter);
```

I've made `letter` into an array of two characters, and am passing the address of the array; that matches the `%s` scan conversion that you've used.

Comment: Thank you thank you! this worked! however im still unsure of the underlying mechanics of this, why would i need an array of size 2 to contain 1 letter?? is this because it needs an end of line character or something ??

Comment: The '%s' scan conversion is for a string; strings in C have a zero byte to mark the end. You always need to allow for that extra `char` when dealing with strings in C. But if you specify `%c` instead of `%s`, then `scanf()` will read just one character, and you'd only need to declare a `char` rather than an array, and pass the address of that `char` (i.e., &letter).